# Pegar nome de um ficheiro csv

Tags: php

Eu num site que desenvolvo faço backup de dados em csv o meu problema e que se eu quiser recuperar o backup (através do site ) como tenho uma pasta com vários csv nao consigo saber qual foi o ultimo que foi criado.

Alguém conhece alguma maneira de eu verificar a data que esta no nome porque o nome do ficheiro é deste genéro **nome_2015-11-13_01.42.22_.csv**

Obrigado

Comment: É um csv por dia ou poder tem mais?

Comment: Se o formato padrao for este para todos, você pode usar regex para filtrar a data do nome, veja: https://ideone.com/rionwn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a função [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) para listar todos os arquivos csv, feito isso obtenha a data contida no nome, com o [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) o índice que contém a da ta é o `1` e a hora o `2`, troque os `.` por `:`, adicione essa nova string no array `$novo` depois ordene em forma decrente com [rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$arquivos = glob('temp/*.csv');
$novo = array();
foreach ($arquivos as $item){
    $datahora = explode('_', $item);
    $novo[] = $datahora[1] .' '. str_replace('.', ':', $datahora[2]);
}

rsort($novo);
$backup = array_shift($novo);
echo 'Backup mais recente realizado em: '.  $backup;
```

A saída é algo parecido com:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-11-14 01:42:23
    [1] => 2015-11-14 01:42:22
    [2] => 2015-11-13 01:42:22
    [3] => 2015-11-12 01:42:22
    [4] => 2015-11-10 01:42:22
    [5] => 2015-10-13 01:42:22
)
Backup mais recente realizado em 2015-11-14 01:42:23
```

Answer (score 1):

Percorra o diretório de seus backups e ordene os arquivos por data de criação.

```
<?php

$arquivos = array();
$diretorio = 'caminho/da/pasta/de/backup/';
$manipulador  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($arquivo = readdir($manipulador))) {
    $arquivos[] = $arquivo;
}

$listaArquivos = array();
foreach ($arquivos as $arquivo) {
    $listaArquivos[filemtime($arquivo)] = $arquivo;
}

ksort($listaArquivos);
var_dump($listaArquivos);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para listas os arquivos existe mais de um jeito, conforme apontado nas outras respostas.

De qualquer maneira você vai ter que extrair do nome a porção que se refere a data, por posição ou com expressão regular.

```php
$arquivo = 'nome_2015-11-13_01.42.22_.csv';
$prefixo = 'nome_';
$dataHora = substr(strlen($prefixo), 19);
```

Para converter para data você existem duas maneiras:

1 - com a função [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (necessário PHP >= 5.3.0), nesse caso será retornado um objeto [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d_H.i.s', $dataHora)
```

2 - com a função [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php), será preciso fazer uma conversão do formato, trocando o `_` por `T`, de acordo com os [formatos compostos] aceitos, que retorna uma [estampa de tempo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_temporal):

```
strtotime($dataHora, str_replace('_', 'T', $dataHora));
```